# How to exit a time-out task in goroutine

Tags: go

I want run (v, ctx) to exit when it runs out of time，Here is the code I wrote to help me see if there is a problem or Whether there is a better job?

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "log"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    do := make(chan int)

    rand.Seed(time.Now().Unix())

    s := []int{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600}
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), time.Second*3)
    defer cancel()

    work := func(ctx context.Context) {
        for v := range do {
            run(v, ctx)
        }
    }

    for range [3]struct{}{} {
        go work(ctx)
    }

    for _, v := range s {
        do <- v
    }

    time.Sleep(time.Second * 20)

}

func run(v int, ctx context.Context) {
    select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
        log.Print("timeout")
        return
    default:
        //do something
        log.Print(v)
        time.Sleep(time.Duration(rand.Intn(5)+1) * time.Second)
    }

}
```

I'm a beginner,I have run my code, but I'm not sure if it will be a problem? Can you give me some advice?

Comment: Whether run returns when the context is cancelled depends entirely on what "do something" does. time.Sleep is not a good surrogate because it cannot be cancelled.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple techniques you can use.

First, I would recommend avoiding `range` over the channel since it doesn't support contexts. Use a loop around `select` instead:

```golang
work := func(ctx context.Context) {
    for {
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            return
        case v := <-do:
            run(ctx, v)  // ctx should conventionally be first parameter.
        }
    }
}
```

Within `run` and descendent functions you can detect cancellation via `ctx.Done()` as above, or call `ctx.Err()` and return:

```golang
if err := ctx.Err(); err != nil {
   return // err -- you should capture and return errors from your worker function.
}
```

[`golang.org/x/sync/errgroup.Group`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sync/errgroup#Group) can be used to manage starting goroutines, waiting for them to complete, and capturing the first (if any) error worker functions:

```golang
g, ctx := errgroup.WithContext(ctx)
for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
    g.Go(func() error {
        return work(ctx)
    })
}
if err := g.Wait(); err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Failed:", err)
}
```